# Ошибки компиляции Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, реклама

Пожалуйста, помогите исправить ошибку компиляции.

При компиляции приложения, на разных устройствах возникают разные ошибки.

На эмуляторе 4.1.1 версии андроид и реальном устройстве 4.0.4 вылетает эта ошибка:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/util/ThreadUtil$BackgroundCallback.class
```

На эмуляторе андроид 5.1.1 краш с этим кодом:

```
08-30 16:37:50.845 2095-2162/helmus.finalversion A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf71d25ce in tid 2162 (AsyncTask #1)
08-30 16:37:50.854 2095-2166/helmus.finalversion A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf71d25ce in tid 2166 (AsyncTask #2)
```

При этом на реальных устройствах выше пятой версии все работает отлично.

Ошибка появилась после добавления рекламы от Appodeal. Скорее всего я где-то накосячил. Ниже прикрепляю build.gradle (app) и Android Manifests

build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "helmus.finalversion"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'

    compile project(':unity-ads-1.5.8')
    compile project(':cheetah-mobile-3.4.7')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'

}
```

в манифесте 165 строк, по-этому [вот](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Xz-soiJimeM0FSb01fb2hpaFU/view?usp=sharing) ссылка на xml документ на гугл диске.

Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Решилось удалением библиотек `unity-ads-1.4.7.jar` и `android-support-v4-23.1.1.jar`. Возможно, студия еще будет ругаться на библиотеку `android-support-v7`. Поможет то-же удаление. Конфликт возникает из-за того, что в приложении используется `multidex`, который в свою очередь использует эти самые библиотеки `android-support-v4` и `android-support-v7`